# Do I have to pay for Qt license to develop a commercial application for Symbian OS?

Tags: qt, mobile, licensing, symbian

I have the intention to develop a commercial, closed-source  application for mobile phones.

I've choosen to start with Symbian OS, as I've got a Symbian phone as 
well, and I really like it.
I would like to adopt Qt, because it's actually the way suggested by 
Nokia, and because I know I could port my app quite easily to ios and 
other platforms by using the Qt libraries.

So, having to make the choose between Qt and C/C++/Carbide 
I have one compelling question:
do I have to pay to obtain a license for using the Qt to develop a 
commercial closed-source program?

Truly, I won't to pay for using a development tool, as I'm not sure I 
could return on my investment. Besides, I have also to pay to open an 
account for hosting my app on the stores.

Please feel free to correct my English if it sounds bad. Thnx.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you don't have to pay** for the Qt framework to build commercial or proprietary applications. [GNU LGPL version 2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) allows this, and Qt is licensed under this licence.

Read about the Qt licensing [here](http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing).

Extract:

> This version of Qt is appropriate for the development of Qt applications (proprietary or open source) provided you can comply with the terms and conditions contained in the [GNU LGPL version 2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html).

*Note that LGPL still has some requirements. For example, if you improve the Qt sources to provide your application a better performance or to fix a bug, you have to make the source code of your modifications available to anybody you give (sell; distribute) your application to. As this is not a bad idea per se, one may want to keep such changes private and use it as a competitive advantage.*

See also [FAQ on Qt licensing](http://qt.nokia.com/about/licensing/frequently-asked-questions/) (thanks to Claudio for the comments).

Comment: Doesn't the LGPL (and GPL too) mandate that you provide the changes _to user who receives the binary_ only, and not (necessarily) the ones you got the original source from?

Comment: @Claudio I'm not sure about this. I just tried to read the LGPL, but it's quite complicated to find exactly this rule... Maybe someone else can clarify this? (However, this shouldn't matter if you don't want to change the original source code.)

Comment: The (L)GPL states that the people who receives the binary must also receives its source. If you modify Qt but do not ship binaries to Nokia, what source would you have to provide to Nokia? For the same argument if a company uses _internally_ a modified (L)GPL program it doesn't have to give its source to anyone. Of course if you don't modify Qt you can use it as you want (besides perhaps static linking). See also [FAQ on Qt licensing](http://qt.nokia.com/about/licensing/frequently-asked-questions/)

Comment: @Claudio As I understand it, "the people who receives the binary [of Qt] must also receives its source" -- this means if I modify Qt and use it in my closed-source application, I only have to provide the  source of my modified Qt version to anybody I provide the binaries of this Qt version (which are those who I sell my programm). So it doesn't harm me as long as I don't want to use the modification of Qt as my competitive advantage. Right? Thanks for this and the link you posted, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's the main idea in LGPL. Even so, it might be a good idea to seek for legal advice, or at least ask directly to the author (licences are always quite complex).